# Is there a good way not to hand-write all twelve required Container functions for a custom type in C++?

Tags: c++, iterator

On stackoverflow I asked, [what is the preferred way to expose custom STL-style iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231664/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-expose-custom-stl-style-iteration).  The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39232329/8877) seems to be to implement **twelve** functions: six members, six non-members (perhaps using some macros to assist).

In C#, I can do about the same with just a single function using `yield return`; C++ is great, but it's things like this that can give it a really bad reputation.  Is there a good (i.e., macro-free?) way to not have to write these twelve functions?

Comment: Did you read through the answers and comments on the linked question? The answer you are looking for is already there.

Comment: IME the best way to not [insert unnecessarily painful thing here] in C++ is to not use C++.  It's one of those "now you have two problems" things.

Comment: @Dan That's the thing.  I do, very strongly.  It may not be the worst language ever invented, but it certainly is the worst ever to be taken seriously!

Comment: How many of these classes are you building, and who is maintaining them?  There's some CRTP trickery you can do with templates.  It's typesafe, unlike macros, but I don't think it's any more readable.

Comment: @Dan: "*I'm trying to nicely say "WTF!"*" Well, why are you doing it on Prog.SE? If all you want to do is complain about how a language doesn't make X easy, I'm sure there are plenty of forums where you can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global functions `std::begin` and `std::end` (along with their `c` counterparts in C++14) will find the named member functions of the containers. So there is no need to provide non-member versions of these functions.

Non-member ranges only matter if someone wants to make an unqualified call to `begin`/`end`. And the Container concept in C++ does not present that as a valid interface to containers (not that it should matter to you, since few C++ APIs take containers to begin with). Range-based `for` will look for member `begin/end` before non-members, so you're safe there too.

But the member function you are going to have to write yourself. You can avoid writing the `cbegin/cend` versions by writing `const` versions of `begin/end` and using the CRTP to generate the others:

```
template<typename Derived>
class cbegin_cend
{
public:
    auto cbegin() const {return This()->begin();}
    auto cend() const {return This()->end();}
private:
    auto This() const {return static_cast<const Derived*>(this);}
};
```

To use it, you would do this:

```
class mine : public cbegin_cend<mine>
{
public:
    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator end() const;
};
```

This requires C++14's automatic return type deduction functionality. That's required because otherwise you'd have to type the name of the return type in `cbegin` and `cend`. And the CRTP base class cannot detect that without external help. We could use an external traits class to provide it, but that's extra work the container has to do.

Comment: @Dan: No, he said that they are necessary in order to allow unqualified calls to `begin`/etc to work. If you don't intend to make or support such things, then you don't need them. Certainly, the container requirements don't require it (not that C++ has many functions that use containers as a concept to begin with). And even range-based `for` will prefer member `begin/end` over unqualified `begin/end`

Comment: @Dan: "*But if I don't know how clients are going to use the code, then for maximum flexibility I should support the non-member begin()/etc. calls, right?*" Why should you? Generally speaking, if you don't provide an interface, people won't try to use it. If you say that your interface follows the Container requirements from the standard, then people will expect it to provide that interface. But the Container requirements *don't include* unqualified `begin/end` calls. So why would your users expect you to provide that?

Comment: @Dan: Yes, but the glorious part about ADL in C++ is: You don't have to write that function. It already exists.  `std::begin`. Container writers just try to meet the container requirements.

Answer (score 5):

> On stackoverflow I asked, [what is the preferred way to expose custom STL-style iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39231664/212858)
>
> ... In C#, I can do about the same with just a single function using `yield return`

No, you really can't.

C#'s `yield return` looks similar to a Python generator, which in C++ terms is an [InputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator), the simplest of the six iterator categories described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator).

Your original question implements a [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator), which is significantly more powerful than this - for example, you can do direct random-access binary search on the iterators returned in that code, or sort the contents of a non-const container in-place.

If all you want is a C#/Python style input iterator, you can probably simplify production with CRTP as Cort Ammon suggested in comments, and you can definitely lose the non-const overloads.

---

### A summary of subsequent comments:

> Q: In PogoStickLang, I can create a new pogo stick by just typing `!`. In RocketLang I need to type loads more stuff to make a pogo stick, and it seems over-complex
>
> A: In RocketLang you created a rocket, which is why it's more complex than a pogo stick. Either
>
> - create a pogo stick if that's all you want. It's more work when not using a language tightly focused on the unique needs of pogo stick-users, but still less work than creating a rocket
> - or, create a rocket and actually take advantage of all the things it can do that a pogo stick can't, like flying to the moon or incinerating your enemies.

*No, this isn't entirely serious. No, I'm not suggesting that C# is a toy language, and no, I'm not suggesting this is a proportionate comparison of the relative powers of Input- and RandomAccessIterators. I don't have anything against pogo sticks and rarely, if ever, incinerate my enemies*.

Comment: That is a good point - if the container is immutable, only provide `const` iterators. If it is mutable, only provide non-`const` iterators since they can be used in a `const` context anyway.

Comment: A lot of developers are looking for the features they expect to see, and ignoring the ones they didn't know existed. If you limit yourself to implementing what they expect, it'll be less typing, although still more than with language support. On the plus side, the more powerful iterator categories do actually exist in C++, where C# has language support for the most basic category and no support at all for the others.

Answer (score 1):

No.

As the linked question states, the Container trait in C++ indicates you need twelve functions for iteration in various circumstances: const v. non-const, member v. non-member, etc.

You may be able to use a macro to avoid some of the boilerplate, but now you have less visibility into your code. What if there is a bug in the generated code? Can you look at your C++ source file and see it? No: the extra step of inspecting preprocessor output is required. There is a reason why macros are generally avoided in good C++ code outside of include guards (yes `#pragma once` exists but include guards are still common). They makes code less readable and harder to maintain. This is part of the reason why C++ gives us tools such as templates and traits, to address the root cause of some of the reasons for using macros.

Functions to acquire iterators are generally short and simple. Just hand-write the functions and be done with it.

Comment: Different languages are different.

Comment: How often do you really write (real) custom containers  ?

Comment: What, the reputation of C++ being a lower-level language than C# and that has decades more baggage?

Comment: @Dan If you want simple to write custom containers do not use C++. Simple as that.

Comment: That's crazy, adding the different begin() and end() functions doesn't take that long anyway

Comment: Any language has complexity. Modern languages like C# hide a lot of it in library code. In C++, you often have to hit that complexity head-on and deal with stuff like writing custom iterators. But that lets the code that _uses_ those iterators be simpler.

Comment: Car analogy: C++ is like a 1970s muscle car. You buy it, then complain about having to tune the carburetor. After all, your other brand new 2016 car is all digital and tunes its fuel injection automatically around ten times per second. Both cars have plenty of horsepower and do well in the quarter mile, but the classic one looks nicer and makes you more attractive to the opposite gender. It just takes more work.

Comment: Maybe "yield return;" in C# allows some programming style that would be done completely differently by a C++ developper (maybe function object, lambda, exposing containers) depending on what you need.